# No error when Google App Engine sends email but the recipient does not receive any emails

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to send an email using python and google appengine using the code below:
**main2.app**

```
   import webapp2
  from google.appengine.api import mail from google.appengine.api import users

 class InviteFriendHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user is None:
      login_url = users.create_login_url(self.request.path)
      self.redirect(login_url)
      return
    to_addr = "madhurima.basu@gmail.com"
    if not mail.is_email_valid(to_addr):
        # Return an error message...
        pass

    message = mail.EmailMessage()
    message.sender = user.email()
    message.to = to_addr
    message.body = """
   I've invited you to Example.com!

   To accept this invitation, click the following link,
   or copy and paste the URL into your browser's address
   bar:

    %s
    """ % generate_invite_link(to_addr)

    message.send()

   **app.yaml**
   application: r-email
    version: 1
  runtime: python27
 api_version: 1
 threadsafe: no


handlers:
- url: /.*
script: main2.py
```

When I deploy this code to google engine, it runs w/o any error but the recipient does not receive any emails. Also in the dashboard, it says 39% "Recipients Emailed" ..

Comment: are you using a custom domain? If so, can you please check your spam folder.

Comment: Please check your indentation - Python is whitespace sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

check you sender email address, there are very specific requirements. You can set the reply-to address to your user's address if that's what you need, but the actual sender has to be one of the following types:

- The address of a registered administrator for the application. You can add administrators to an application using the Administration Console.
- The address of the user for the current request signed in with a Google Account. You can determine the current user's email address with the Users API. The user's account must be a Gmail account, or be on a domain managed by Google Apps.
- Any valid email receiving address for the app (such as xxx@APP-ID.appspotmail.com).
- Any valid email receiving address of a domain account, such as support@example.com. Domain accounts are accounts outside of the Google domain with email addresses that do not end in @gmail.com or @APP-ID.appspotmail.com.

more here.. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail

Comment: 1.I have checked all the folders(Inbox/spam/etc) and none of the emails appear there.
2.The address of the user for the current request signed in with a Google Account. You can determine the current user's email address with the Users API. The user's account must be a Gmail account, or be on a domain managed by Google Apps. - I am logged in using my email address i.e. madhurima.basu@gmail.com.

3.Indentation seems correct coz I have run it by "Check Modules" in the Python IDLE.

Comment: oh thats ok ..you were trying to help!!!Anything else that I can try out??My intention is to create an HTML contact form and send out the content to an email address using Python since I'm using google appengine to host the site..

Comment: I would try to get the most basic email sending first, ie, drop the generate_invite_link. Also I notice you're not setting a subject. Other than that I'm not sure..